# Method invocation output confusion

Tags: java

I am confused with the output (i.e after `showValue` method in `Mno` class)

```
class Lab2 {
    public static void main(String[] aa) {
        int ab=98;
        System.out.println("ab in main before\t:"+ab);
        Mno ref = new Mno();
        ref.showValue(ab);

        System.out.println("ab in Main After\t:"+ab);
    }
}

class Mno {
    void showValue(int ab) {
        System.out.println("ab in showvalue before\t:"+ab);
        if (ab!=0)
            showValue(ab/10);
        System.out.println("ab in showvalue After\t:"+ab);
    }
}
```

I got the following output...how it is printing show value after 0,9,98....?

```
F:\Train\oops>java Lab2
ab in main before       :98
ab in showvalue before  :98
ab in showvalue before  :9
ab in showvalue before  :0
ab in showvalue After   :0
ab in showvalue After   :9
ab in showvalue After   :98
ab in Main After        :98
```

Comment: Java pass by copy, not by reference

Answer (score 2):

In Java only copy of the variables are passed during method calls.

In the case of primitives its a copy of the value and in case of Object its a copy of the reference to the Object.

So the value of the int ab in the main method would not change as you are passing a copy to the showValue method.

Answer (score 0):

You are making recursive calls here :

```
ab in showvalue before :98
showValue(98);
ab in showvalue before :9
 -> showValue(9);
  ab in showvalue before :0
  -> showValue(0); //if returns true here, so no more recursive call
  ab in showvalue after :0
 ab in showvalue after :9
ab in showvalue before :98
```

Comment: thank u GV , actually i did't understood the code properly that "shovalue after" statement was there inside showvalue() mathod

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling the function `showValue` each time that `ab!=0`, which, coupled with the fact that Java is passing copies of `ab`, results in your output appearing in a pyramid form.

All of the `ab in showvalue before` outputs are caused as you call the function from within itself, passing a copy of `ab` each time. Seeing as the value of `ab` never actually changed, once all of the `showValue` calls have been evaluated, the loop unravels and prints the old copies in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Its a recursion call. Control of the program returns to that point where it called itself with different value.
See your call->

ShowValue(98)->ShowValue(9)->ShowValue(0)

Got it?